# what is the meaning of "native" in "native year"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in my history book which was:

In the native year 1203, corresponding with 1796-97, the land advertised for sale comprehended.....

I can't figure out what the word "native" means in this context.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. What event and setting is the text describing? Who might be the natives in this case? Quoting some additional context might help, and the name of the book and author.

Comment: Hard to say, without more context. I would guess that the writer is comparing the local ("native") calendar with the standard European calendar.

Comment: The source is *History of India* by Dr Malti Malik, quoting from *Fifth Report from the [British Parliamentary] Select Committee on the Affairs of the East India Company*.  The particular piece appears to be about Bengal, the "native calendar" will be the Bengali one.

Answer (score 2):

Here the word is being used in the sense of:

> grown, produced, or originating in a particular place or in the vicinity : Local
>   <sub>definition 6a from [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/native)</sub>

The people in the area counted it as the year 1203; in the standard reckoning used by most of the world, it was either 1796 or 1797 (because the local year did not start at the same time as the standard year).

Comment: It would appear to be the Bengali calendar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_calendars